# Flask + MySQL + PHP + Docker-Compose = Pain

Tags: mysql, docker, flask, sqlalchemy, docker-compose

im trying to build a simple To do app with docker-compose having 3 Containers: One Flask Rest API with sqlalchemy and marshmallow, one PHP to call my Rest-Api and one MySQL Database. The error im getting is:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, 
"Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)") 
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

And i cant call my rest api from my php container. 
Here is the code with the important lines:

my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.1' #compose version

services: 
flaskapi-service:
 build: 
  context: ./restapi #relative to docker-compose file directory
  dockerfile: DOCKERFILE
 volumes: 
  - ./restapi:/usr/src/app #mounting
 ports:
  - 5001:5001 #host:container
 depends_on:
  - db
 restart: on-failure

db:
 image: mysql:latest
 restart: always
 environment:
  MYSQL_USER: username
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
  MYSQL_DATABASE: todo
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
 ports:
   - "3306:3306"

php-page:
 build:
  context: ./frontend
  dockerfile: DOCKERFILE
 volumes:
  - ./frontend:/var/www/html #mount
 ports: 
  - 5002:80 #host:container
 depends_on: 
  - flaskapi-service
```

my rest-api:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
import pymysql

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 
'mysql+pymysql://username:password@db:3306/todo'

#order matters: ORM before serialization tool
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)
```

how im calling the rest-api from php:

```
 <?php
    $date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $data = array(
        'description' => $_POST['description'],
        'deadline' => $_POST['deadline'],
        'createdAt' => $date_time,
        'finished' => 'false'
    );

    $encodedJSON = json_encode($data);

    //Initiate cURL-handle
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://flaskapi-service/todo',
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $encodedJSON,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/json')
    ));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $result;
    curl_close($ch);
    header('Location: index.php');
 ?>
```

Any help is appreciated and the correct answer marked as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by downgrading from latest MySQL Version image to 5.7:

```
mysql:5.7
```

I dont have any clue why this should work since the returned error must be something e.g a misconfiguration with my  docker and its networking and shouldnt have nothing to do with mysql. Maybe this helps someone.

Edit: allways check if your Database container is up before trying to connect since docker compose ist starting all containers simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "@db" in your SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, you want the actual address at which you can find the db container from your server.

You can, for example, find out what your docker machine ip is using

```
$ docker-machine ip
```

And then replace that ip in your URI. e.g.

```
'mysql+pymysql://username:password@192.168.0.123:3306/todo'
```

They might even be on the same host if all containers and on the same machine, so give this a shot:

```
'mysql+pymysql://username:password@localhost:3306/todo'
```

You can find other ways to determine the IP address of your MySQL instance [in this discussion](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/95).

Comment: `db` should be resolvable as a DNS hostname (because they’re both on the same non-default Docker bridge network, because Docker Compose creates one for you, and because Compose also creates network aliases matching the service names) and using it is absolutely preferable to trying to figure out any specific IP address.  The questioner may not be using Docker Machine at all.

Comment: Didn't know this, thanks for letting me know. What's the protocol here, do I delete my solution?

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, but if i try it with localhost i get (Errno 99, Cannot assign requested address) and no im not using docker machine at all